# Design Pattern: In what manner to structure tables in DB to: Restrict access to articles on a website to only subscribed users?

Tags: reactjs, database, postgresql, design-patterns, permissions

This is my 1st question on stackoverflow. So please forgive if it doesn't meet the standards:

**DATABASE USED: PostgreSQL v11.2**

I'm creating a **react.js** app to show show articles to signed-in users. **These users can be either:

(i)** those who have subscribed to one of the subscription plans, or,
**(ii)** simply signed-in and surfing through but not subscribed yet.
(THIS PART IS MANAGED - NO PROBLEM HERE)

An article can belong to different "categories".
(THIS PART IS MANAGED - NO PROBLEM HERE)

Now, **for subscribed users, certain 'categories' of articles are to be shown,** which normal users can't see.

I want to create a database structure that will handle this visibility based on whether the user is subscribed or not.

- `USER` table columns (that matter):
  id, name,
  **is_subscribed** (Boolean)
- `CATEGORY` table columns (that matter):
  id, cat_name
- `ARTICLE` table columns (that matter):
  id, title
- `ARTICLE_CATEGORY` table columns:
  id, article_id, category_id
- `SUBSCRIPTION` table columns:
  id, plan_name, price, decsription

How to go ahead with it?
I haven't built the structure yet to implement this.

**WHAT SHOULD BE A BETTER APPROACH?**

**(1) Should I do it at the category/article level?**
For ex.: "ARTICLE_CATEGORY" and "ARTICLE" tables will contain a Boolean column "subscribers_only".

**OR**

**(2) Should I maintain a separate table linking my subscription plans with categories/articles?**

My model for USER looks like this:

```
const User = sequelize.define("user", {
    full_name: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
    email: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
    password: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
    email_verify_token: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
    is_email_verified: { type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN },
    is_subscribed: { type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN },
    ... <many more columns>
  });
```

My model for SUBSCRIPTION_PLAN looks like this:

```
const SubscriptionPlan = sequelize.define("subscription_plan", {
    plan_name: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER },
    price: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER }
    ... <many more columns>
  });
```

My model for SUBSCRIBERS looks like this:

```
const Subscriber = sequelize.define("subscriber", {
    user_id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER },
    subscription_id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER }
    ... <many more columns>
  });
```

My model for ARICLE looks like this:

```
const Article = sequelize.define("article", {
    title: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
    url: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
    display_pic: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
    ... <many more columns>
  });
```

My model for ARICLE_CATEGORY looks like this:

```
const ArticleCategory = sequelize.define("article_catgeory", {
    article_id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER },
    category_id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER }
    ... <many more columns>
  });
```

Comment: You need to give us an example of what you have tried and show any code/work related to the issue. Also, you just say "database". Which database, which version.

Comment: @evilfish Apologies for incomplete data earlier.
Database: Postgres v11.2

Comment: @evilfish Also, I've updated the question with "What should be a better approach" section. I've not written any code to implement this particlar thing. I've to build my database structure, and had this doubt at that stage itself - before having a complete database. I want to know what approach should I follow to build by DB structure. Any help would be great.